# Gradle assemble of an Android project failed, can't find R.txt

Tags: android, gradle

Sorry for my poor English. I'm trying to migrate my project to Gradle with Android Studio, but currently the build fails during `processDebugResources`.

error info:

> Execution failed for task ':app:processAdultDebugResources'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Projects\YYM\app\build\symbols\adult\debug\R.txt (系统找不到指定的文件。)(That Chinese means "System cannot find the file")

In addition, I found that in the `build` path of my project there was a `R.java` file under a strange path: `build/source/r/debug/--output-text-symbols`.

Here is a part of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 78
        versionName "1.7.72"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi"
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        weightloss {
            packageName "com.yesudoo.yymweightloss"
        }
        adult {
            packageName "com.yesudoo.yymadult"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix ".dev"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

I'm new in Gradle, and thanks in advance for any pointers on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So the way I fixed this was:

inside my **androidTest** folder, I had a **java** folder with my test files. But gradle requires you to have some resources inside test so that it generates the **R.txt** file. So what I did was created a **res** folder inside **androidTest** and added a **values/strings.xml** folder with one string resource.

This allowed my tests to build and run!

Comment: Do you have some official documentation for this? I tried your fix, works but I need to explain it to my team :))

Comment: Goodddddddddddd

Comment: @Prem I followed the above steps but still having the same issue.is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, beginning when I fumbled around adding a second sub-subfolder to my assets directory. Removing the folder (basically undoing what I did to cause the problem) didn't help, which indicated it may be a problem with caches. The accepted answer may work, if by changing the manifest file you trigger Android Studio to invalidate its caches (apparently this is more than clean and rebuild, as I tried that several times).

Simple thing to try: go to File->Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, maybe this helps someone

`build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

`gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Sync Now.

Answer (score -3):

Solved. The reason is that the AndroidManifest.xml file had something wrong, but gradle(or lint?) didn't figure it out. Thus the R.txt file couldn't be generated. As soon as I amended the AndroidManifest.xml file, the problem was gone.
Sorry again for my poor English.

Comment: what did you have to amend in your AndroidManifest? I have the same problem, but my Manifest looks fine

Comment: same as @Prem: how can this be an accepted answer? isn't it required to give a bit more than just a hint of a solution? "something wrong" #wtf?

Comment: I just deleted the build folder and rebuild the project then its working fine.